# Disabling a dropdown list

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

First of all, I posted this in Joomla Stackexchange because I have created a simple html file and the disabling of the dropdown works.

I have this javascript code right here:

```
function disable()
 {
   var x = document.getElementById('jform_report');
if(x==null)
    {
        alert('null');
    }
else
    {
        x.disabled = true;
    }       
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

I even created this long code just to make sure that I am getting the Id of the dropdown. Which I got successfully. The problem is, the dropdown still remains enabled. I tried this code with other fields such as a textbox. They work except for dropdown lists.

Also, when I use inspect element in the page, this code appears just below the code tag of my dropdown list please see the highlighted area:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is in chosen. You are disabling just your select, but chosen renders its content. Please [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153417/disable-jquery-chosen-dropdown) for the possible solution.